# MatLab - fscanf Issues With Arduino

Tags: matlab, serial-port, arduino

I have several `Serial.println` statements in my Arduino sketch.  All of them are strings, except one which is an integer.  The integer is the only variable I want to plot in real-time using MatLab's `fscanf`.

I have 3 `Serial.println` statements that print strings.  2 of them reside within the `setup` and the 3rd resides in the `loop`.  The integer is the 4th that comes directly after the latter string.

After reading the documentation I found that you can filter what you want, but I now get this error:

```
Warning: Unsuccessful read: Matching failure in format. 
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in serialHRM (line 12)
   x(i) = fscanf(ard, '%*s %d');
```

My MatLab code :

```
ard = serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A601EQJ5', 'BaudRate', 9600);

fopen(ard);

i = 1;
N = 50;
x = zeros(0, N);

while i <= N

   x(i) = fscanf(ard, '%*s %d');
   plot(x)
   hold on
   axis([1, N, 0, 150])
   drawnow;
   i = i +1;

end
```

EDIT:

Thanks - I've just printed the first and second line, which is all the serial prints I have.  I did say 3 `strings`, and 1 `int`, but 1 of the `strings` is in an `if` statement, so only 1 will print in the `setup` function.  Here is all the lines from MatLab:

```
tline =

Card Failed or Ready


EDU>> tline = fgetl(ard)

tline =

BPM: 100
```

Arduino `Serial` prints:

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Card Failed or Ready");
}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("BPM: "); Serial.println(BPM);
  delay(1000);
}
```

The variable I am only interested is the `int` `BPM`.

Answer (score 0):

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be
>   the same.

Error does what it says on the tin.  `x(i)`, is able to hold one number, no more and no less.  So either `fscanf(ard, '%*s %d');` is returning empty, or it is returning more than one number.

The most likely reason is that you are not doing anything to read/discard the setup strings, so `fscanf` is attempting to read one of them as `%d` and returning empty.  To debug, try using `fgetl` instead, and just print-out each received line.  If it's just the header lines, read them in before the loop starts.

You could also put in some error checking in the loop - instead of just assigning the output of `fscanf` directly to `x`, first drop it into a temporary variable. If the output is empty, you can either just continue until you get a good value, or put something like `NaN` into `x` to indicate a failed read.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited my post in order to provide more info after your post.  In order to see if something is empty, would I use `isempty()` within an `if` statement?

Comment: Yes - I would actually use the reverse: `if ~isempty(temp)` (`temp` being the variable you assign the output of `fscanf` to, and then only assign to `x`/increment your counter/redraw graph if there's actually data in `temp`.